# Почему не работает position: relative у элемента elvo__window?

Tags: html, css

```css
.elvo__section {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: 770px;
}

.elvo__img {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}

.elvo__window {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 510px;
  width: 460px;
  /*margin-left: 30px;*/
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="elvo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="elvo__section">
      <div class="elvo__window">
        <p class="elvo__title">Компания elvo</p>
        <p class="elvo__input">Лучшая компания</p>
        <p class="elvo__text">
          Строительная компания ELVO является проектной организацией, которая отвечает за подготовку всего проекта, в соответствии с договором или контрактом.
        </p>
      </div>

      <img class="elvo__img" src="Images/elvo.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что он не работает? Он работает прекрасно. Что подразумевает ваше "не работает"?

Comment: Просто элемент с position: relative находится под фотографией с position : absolute
Должно же быть наоборот, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: С чего бы? `position: relative` на это никак не влияет. Он нужен для того, чтобы дочерние элементы позиционировались относительно него. В вашем случае все проще. У вас два элемента, один после другого. Соответственно выше будет тот, который встретился позже. А это картинка, тег `img`. Хотите исправить — ставьте картинку раньше `elvo_window`. или добавьте `elvo_window` свойство `z-index`